# Delete empty option from select2 with ng-model directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-select2

I have 2 empty options in my select2: 1 I added to html to make my placeholder works and 1 I have no idea where it appears from.

How can I remove the empty options by jquery?
The difficulty is that I can't get div from select's dropdown to check div's text() is empty because it's also span in div.

Example of empty div:

```
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted" role="presentation">
  <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-12" role="option">
    <span class="select2-match"></span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Exapmle of filled div:

```
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted" role="presentation">
  <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-12" role="option">
    <span class="select2-match"></span>
    "Text1"
  </div>
</li>
```

Here's pluner to demonstrate my problem(at my real html I have only 1 empty option):
http://plnkr.co/edit/pO71Wr0k9BM2D2Z5yQWu?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use the [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)  function to only select the empty options and remove them with [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
 $('select option:not(:first)')
        .filter(function() {
            return !this.value || $.trim(this.value).length == 0 || $.trim(this.text).length == 0;
        })
       .remove();
```

Comment: how the filter function will look like if my empty option has a value but hasn't text?

Comment: This will remove all the option elements who dont have a value or dont have text.

Comment: Your answer partly hepls me. But it doesn't remove such options that appears after I chose them. So this oprion appear: <option value="? string:0 ?"></option> or <option value="? string:1 ?"></option> or <option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option> Maybe it's select2 issue?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't understand what you mean, can you put it in a plnkr or jsfiddle maybe? I'm confused

Comment: I'll try. I get that this issue appears when use select2 and angular ng-model

Comment: I edited, try that, that way all the options are selected but the first. So there is one empty option left.

Comment: I don't know what you mean then

Comment: I fixed my problem. So I needed to add options by using ng-options. Before I used .append() . And angular added empty option to show in value what option I selected.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in your options.js script you are adding new three options with text: 'Text1, Text2, Text3'.
If you remove this code  then it will be with your three empty options in html.
Also if you are adding empty into select empty option you will see them.
If select fill with data like this you will see three options with data and placeholder:

```
    <select id="select", multiple="true">
      <option value="one">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
      <option value="three">Three</option>
    </select>
```

[image]

Comment: kipris What do you want then?

Answer (score 0):

a working demo as per your need can be seen at [`Plnk.co...`](http://plnkr.co/edit/hbI4ufZfOBmOr8zN4kD3?p=preview)

I am not usual to plnkr so incase if you unable to check the link or files please let me know i will send you the file.

I made some changes in your js files, and I hope this will help you.